# Delete all elements that hasn't a specific child using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a block of items like :

```
<div class="owl-item cloned">
 <div class="item"> some other  tags, text, content in item </div>
</div>

<div class="owl-item cloned">
</div>

<div class="owl-item cloned">
 <div class="item"> some other  tags, text, content in item </div>
</div>

<div class="owl-item cloned">
</div>
```

So, I have a parent with class  `owl-item` where I want to check if this element is empty (doesn't have any other child), if yes, delete this element. If no, skip.

So, after execution of my small script, I want to have just :

```
<div class="owl-item cloned">
 <div class="item"> some other  tags, text, content in item </div>
</div>
    <div class="owl-item cloned">
 <div class="item"> some other  tags, text, content in item </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour] and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) Do your research, [search](/help/searching) for related topics on SO, and give it a go. ***If*** you get stuck and can't get unstuck after doing more research and searching, post a [mcve] of your attempt and say specifically where you're stuck. People will be glad to help. Good luck!

Comment: Please always show your coding attempts.

Comment: [**How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users before posting a Question?**](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/261593/448144)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `:empty` selector then call `remove()` on them:

```js
$('.owl-item.cloned:empty').remove();
```

```css
.owl-item {
  border: 1px solid #C00;
  min-height: 1em;
  margin: 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="owl-item cloned">
  <div class="item"> some other tags, text, content in item </div>
</div>
<div class="owl-item cloned"></div>
<div class="owl-item cloned">
  <div class="item"> some other tags, text, content in item </div>
</div>
<div class="owl-item cloned"></div>
```

Note that for this to work you cannot have any whitespace text nodes within the element.

If you do have some whitespace, then you can use `filter()` instead:

```js
$('.owl-item.cloned').filter(function() {
  return $(this).children().length === 0;
}).remove();
```

```css
.owl-item {
  border: 1px solid #C00;
  min-height: 1em;
  margin: 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="owl-item cloned">
  <div class="item"> some other tags, text, content in item </div>
</div>
<div class="owl-item cloned">
</div>
<div class="owl-item cloned">
  <div class="item"> some other tags, text, content in item </div>
</div>
<div class="owl-item cloned">
</div>
```

That said, a better solution would be to not clone the empty element in the first place, assuming that's the reason for the `cloned` class.